# How can I get a specific number of records when performing an IEnumerable query?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, ienumerable

I have an `IEnumerable` and am currently using it to obtain all of the records in a database.

`IEnumerable<Item> items = dbContext.Items.Include(i => i.itemField).AsEnumerable();`

Is there any way for me to obtain only a specific amount of items from the database, like with the following pseudo-code?

`//This would get records 30 - 40 in the database
items = items.Where(i => i.otherField != null).GetNumberOfRecords(30, 40);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sure!

you can use:

```
items  = items.Where(i => i.OtherField != null).Skip(30).Take(10).ToList();
```

Or no ToList() as you prefer :)

Comment: That did the trick. Cheers very much. :)

Comment: a beer would be nice ;)